# How to click on "drop down" in below html

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
   <div id="div_3_1_4" class="Action CoachView CoachView_show" data-eventid="boundaryEvent_6" data-viewid="Action6" data-config="config14" data-bindingtype="" data-binding="" data-type="com.ibm.bpm.coach.Snapshot_a30ea40f_cb24_4729_a02e_25dc8e12dcab.Action">
    <button id="div_3_1_4-lnk" type="button" style="display: none;">
   <a class="p-action-link" href="#action" title="" data-original-title="">
    <i style="display: none;"></i>
    <span>Drop quote</span>
     </a>
     </div>
     </div>
```

how to click on "Drop quote" it will be display in different scenario in the application name & structure will be same as above.

only the text "Drop quote" of link is same but it will display in different position in footer section for different test scenario

ex: //*[@id='div_2_1_4']/a/span
    //*[@id='div_5_1_3']/a/span

so i cant able to use the x path using firebug..

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about exactly what you want but from your description it look like you want to click on the anchor above the "Drop Quote" text. And this html snippet that you have provided can be placed to any here in the html.

If this is true, then you can use the XPATH below to get the anchor element. After span there is `/..` to select the parent anchor.

```
List<Elements> elements = driver.getElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='div_5_1_3']/a/span/.."));
// now loop over the elements
// elements.get(0).click();
```

Let me know if I am missing anything.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
driver=self.webdriver
lst=driver.find_element_by_class_name("p-action-link")
for i in lst:
    if(i.text=="Drop quote")
        i.click()
```

Comment: the above code is in python...and works gud for me...if not let me know